# JavaScript POO and request with Axios

Tags: javascript, mysql, axios, fetch

i am trying to send data to the DataBase with Axios and I normally do it with `literal object`. But i want to create an Object like this:

```
const Food = (foodName, proteins) => {
        this.foodName = foodName;
        this.proteins = proteins;
        ...
    };
```

And then, set a new Object with the user values as input, something like this:

```
 <input
    id="food name"
    name="foodName"
    type="text"
    value={inputValue.foodName}
    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
/>
```

I mean the user can add a food to his own list like:

- when he click on the `add button`, it create a `new Food object` with all fields needed (proteins, bran and so...) : `const pasta = Object.create(Food,name : {value: ...})`
- then all field are sends to the DataBase.

I know it's a little crazy and complicated. But I would like to know if it is possible to proceed like this and if it is a good practice. Or am I just bothering myself for nothing ^^

By advance, thank you!

---

The ReactJS code.

```
// import core
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Foods from "./Foods";

function FoodsAdd() {
    const [food, setFood] = useState("");
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

    class Food {
        constructor(foodName, proteins) {
            this.foodName = foodName;
            this.proteins = proteins;
        }
    }

    // testing to set state with an Object.value
    const addFood = () => {
        const url = "";
        Axios.post(url, food);
    };

    // get inputs values
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        const newFood = { ...inputValue, [name]: value }; // standard way of proceeding
        // what i want to do :
        // const newFood = Object.create(Food, name: {value : { ...inputValue, [name]: value }}) // Or something like that
        console.log(name, value);
        setInputValue(newFood);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setFood(inputValue);
        console.log(food.foodName);
    }, [inputValue]);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Nom de l aliment</legend>
                    <input
                        id="food name"
                        name="foodName"
                        type="text"
                        value={inputValue.test}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    />
                    <label for="food name"></label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Protéines</legend>
                    <input
                        id="proteins"
                        name="proteins"
                        type="number"
                        value={inputValue.proteins}
                        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    />
                    <label for="proteins"></label>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <button>Ajouter</button>
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default FoodsAdd;
```

Comment: You can't use arrow function as constructor. Replace it with a normal function or a class. Then you will be able to create new instance using `new Food()`. Also what does it mean to "sends to the BDD"? BDD usually stands for behaviour driven development.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, sorry i mean DataBase (POST/GET/UPDATE/DELETE)

Comment: And what's wrong with an object factory? `const food = (foodName, proteins) => ({foodName, proteins});`? It sounds like you want to make your code worse... yes, you're bothering yourself for nothing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, hum first I dont know how to really create a new Object with user inputs (with a onClick i guess). I post the entire code bellow :)

Comment: https://github.com/rachOS/front-bon_app.js/blob/feat/test/src/components/Foods/FoodsAdd.jsx